# How to fix my python kivy folder monitoring app from crashing

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I just started work on a gui app with python kivy that lets my monitor folders on my computer, right now I have main.py, main.kv, and watchdog1.py files, when I run my code the application runs and when outputs folder activity to my terminal, however in about a minute it crashes due to to much memory usage.

here is my main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle, Ellipse, Line

from watchdog1 import watch
import _thread


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1000, 800


class MainWindow(AnchorLayout):
    bbox = ObjectProperty(None)
    folders = ["Desktop", "Documents", "Downloads"]
    labels = []
    bools = {}
    

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.add_initial, .1)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.check_active, .1)

    def add_initial(self, dt):
        for f in self.folders:
            self.add_folder(f)
        
    def add_folder(self, text):
        f = Label(text=text)
        s = CheckBox()
        b = BoxLayout()
        b.add_widget(f)
        b.add_widget(s)
        self.bbox.add_widget(b)
  
        self.labels.append(text)
        self.bools[text] = 0
    
    def check_active(self, dt):
        for widget in self.bbox.children:
            t = widget.children[1].text
            b = widget.children[0].active

            if b is True and self.bools[t] == 0:
                print(t, "is active")
                watch(f"C:/Users/Chris/{t}")
                self.bools[t] = 1
            elif b is False:
                self.bools[t] = 0
            
                


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        self.title = "Kivy Watchdog"
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

and my main.kv

```
MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    bbox: bbox
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: dp(30)
            Label:
                text: "Watchdog"
        BoxLayout:
            Label: 
                text: "Folders\nto\nMonitor"
                size_hint: .1, 1
            BoxLayout:
                canvas:
                    Color: 
                        rgba: .2, .2, .2, 1
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                orientation: "vertical"
                spacing: 10
                id: bbox
```

and my watchodg1.py

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

def watch(p):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = p
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()
```

here is a screen shot of what happens:
[image: The Lower circle shows the logging works and the large one shows the error]

Comment: There is very little code here that would consume memory.   The .1 second recheck interval and the "recursive" keyword I wonder about.  What does `recursive=True` do, and what happens if you slow the recheck rate to 1 second intervals?

Comment: I tried changing recursive to False and changing the recheck rate but the result was the same, widows says that the app is not responding

Comment: I just thought of something, could the error come from the watch function, because it never returns anything and it never stops does that mean that python never leaves the function to continue on?

Comment: I assumed it would break out of that loop because of exception or something.  But your `check_active` function will keep getting called, and those calls would buffer up, presumably.  (and your bool won't be set until the function returns, you should probably set it before the call)  But why aren't you getting a long loist of prints?  unless print won't appear until after the event?

Comment: An easy way to check is to set an "in-function" flag at the top of the check_active function and raise an error if it is already set on entry.  Then set it at the start of function execution and unset it just before returning.